# ServiceStack DTO Mapping Issue

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

We are seeing an issue in 4.0.56 that we've seen before (see UPDATE 3 of [ServiceStack - [Reference] or [Ignore]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133236/servicestack-reference-or-ignore)) - namely, the Employee's ID property is being populated with the TitleID value.

The Request DTO is:

```
[Route("/employees", "GET")]
public class FindEmployeesRequest : QueryDb<Employee>,
    IJoin<Employee, EmployeeType>,
    IJoin<Employee, Department>,
    IJoin<Employee, Title> {

    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public int[] IDs { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string[] UserIDs { get; set; }
    public int? EmployeeTypeID { get; set; }
    public int[] EmployeeTypeIDs { get; set; }
    public int? DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public int[] DepartmentIDs { get; set; }
    public int? TitleID { get; set; }
    public int[] TitleIDs { get; set; }
    public string LastNameStartsWith { get; set; }
    public DateTime[] DateOfBirthBetween { get; set; }
    public DateTime[] HireDateBetween { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool? IsEligibleToOrderLunch { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Template = "(MONTH({Field}) = {Value})", Field = "DateOfBirth")]
    public int? BirthMonth { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Template = "(DAY({Field}) = {Value})", Field = "DateOfBirth")]
    public int? BirthDay { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Template = "({Field} LIKE '%(Incoming)')", Field = "EmployeeTypeName")]
    public bool? IsIncoming { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Template = "(FirstName LIKE {Value} OR LastName LIKE {Value} OR PreferredName LIKE {Value})", ValueFormat = "%{0}%", Field = "ID")]
    public string NameSearch { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Template = "(FirstName LIKE {Value} OR LastName LIKE {Value} OR PreferredName LIKE {Value} OR Department.Name LIKE {Value} OR Title.Name LIKE {Value})", ValueFormat = "%{0}%", Field = "ID")]
    public string BasicSearch { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Template = "({Field} LIKE {Value})", Field = "EmployeeTypeName", ValueFormat = "%{0}%")]
    public string EmployeeTypeSearch { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Template = "({Field} LIKE {Value})", Field = "DepartmentName", ValueFormat = "%{0}%")]
    public string DepartmentSearch { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Template = "({Field} LIKE {Value})", Field = "TitleName", ValueFormat = "%{0}%")]
    public string TitleSearch { get; set; }
}
```

Basically any request that does a "SELECT * FROM" exhibits the issue - here's some SQL from Profiler for "/employees?id=101&fields=*":

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * 
FROM "Employee" INNER JOIN "EmployeeType" ON
("EmployeeType"."ID" = "Employee"."EmployeeTypeID") INNER JOIN "Department" ON
("Department"."ID" = "Employee"."DepartmentID") INNER JOIN "Title" ON
("Title"."ID" = "Employee"."TitleID")
WHERE "Employee"."ID" = @0',N'@0 int',@0=101
```

When I run this query myself, "Employee"."ID" is 101 but in the response from the service, it's 67 (the TitleID):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a naked wildcard `?fields=*` on it own, it needs to include the table prefix e.g. `?fields=employee.*` as [mentioned in the docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/AutoQuery-RDBMS#wildcards) which is a short-hand of manually specifying each field in the table.